# Change in connection forms under change of frame

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles, connections

Let $\nabla$ be a linear connection in a vector bundle $\pi:E\to M$. Fix $X\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ and a local frame $s_1,\ldots,s_k\in \Gamma(E_U)$. It seems to me that the plan is to use linear algebra ideas to study the operator $\nabla_X$ in $\Gamma(E)$, great. So one writes $$\nabla_Xs_j = \omega^i_{\hspace{.5ex}j}(X)s_i$$and proves that the $\omega^i_{\hspace{.5ex}j}$ are one-forms. Wonderful.

Now comes my question. Take another local frame $\overline{s_1},\ldots,\overline{s_k}\in\Gamma(E_U)$. Write $\overline{s_j} = h^i_{\hspace{.5ex}j}s_i $ for some convenient smooth functions $h^i_{\hspace{.5ex}j}$. Repeating the above discussion for this new frame, and fiddling around, I find out that $$\overline{\omega^i_{\hspace{.5ex}j}} h^k_{\hspace{.5ex}i}= \omega^k_{\hspace{.5ex}i}h^i_{\hspace{.5ex}j} + {\rm d}h^k_{\hspace{.5ex}j}.$$
I expected the first term but not the ${\rm d}h^k_{\hspace{.5ex}j}$ (apart from the Leibniz rule, I mean). What is the interpretation for the extra term?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ivo, in heuristic terms, the second term is there because the frames are twisting relative to one another. (In the most rudimentary setting, if I watch you walking in a bus, I see a different speed if the bus is moving relative to me.) But you can see it even in the simplest case of surfaces. Suppose the new (orthonormal) frame $\overline e_1,\overline e_2$ is at a (variable) angle $\theta$ from the original frame $e_1,e_2$. Then the rate at which $\overline e_1$ twists toward $\overline e_2$ is given by the *sum* of the rate at which $e_1$ twists toward $e_2$ *and* the rate at which $\theta$ is changing---all of this along some path or direction, instantaneously.

By the way, if you solve for the matrix $\overline\omega$, multiplying by $h^{-1}$ on the right, you should recognize $dh\cdot h^{-1}$ as the (right-invariant) Maurer-Cartan form of the structure group (the orthogonal group in the case I was alluding to).